# Printing multiple list name on the legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to print list name on the legend instead of printing lists. Any idea?
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

m = [x,y]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
#j = ["1","1","1","1","1"]

for i in m:
    ax.plot(i, label='$variable = %s$'%i)

# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

In the figure on legend I want to have variable = x and variable = y

Answer (score 0):

Here might be a possibility:

```
import numpy as np

m = [x,y]
n = ["x","y"]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
#j = ["1","1","1","1","1"]

for i,j in zip(m,n):
    ax.plot(i, label='$variable = %s$'%j)

# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

#Working code.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `['x','y']` as first argument to ax.legend method.

```
ax.legend(['x','y'], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is printing the list is because of the line:

```py
m = [x,y]
```

As x and y are variables containing arrays python is printing the arrays. Assuming you want the array names, i.e. "x" and "y" in the same capacity you would have to do something like:

```py
m = [x,y]
n=['x','y']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
#j = ["1","1","1","1","1"]

for i in n:
    ax.plot(i, label='$variable = %s$'%i)
```

You could also create a dictionary:

```py
m = {'x':x,'y':y}
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
#j = ["1","1","1","1","1"]

for i in m:
    ax.plot(i, label='$variable = %s$'%i)
```